# Trying to implement something similar to type classes in C++ but getting a segfault

Tags: c++, haskell, inheritance, typeclass

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ISignalFilter;

template <typename F>
class ProductFilter;

template <typename T>
class ISignalFilter {
   public:
    virtual T filtered_value(const T& value) {
        (void)value;
        std::cout << "Base case usage of method not allowed";
        std::abort();
    };
    virtual ProductFilter<T> operator*(ISignalFilter<T>& other) {
        return ProductFilter<T>(*this, other);
    }
};

template <typename F>
class ProductFilter : public ISignalFilter<F> {
   public:
    ProductFilter(ISignalFilter<F>& a, ISignalFilter<F>& b) {
        a_ = &a;
        b_ = &b;
    }

    F filtered_value(const F& value) override {
        return b_->filtered_value(a_->filtered_value(value));
    }
    ISignalFilter<F>* a_;
    ISignalFilter<F>* b_;
};

template <typename T>
class IdentityFilter : public ISignalFilter<T> {
   public:
    IdentityFilter() {}
    T filtered_value(const T& value) override { return value; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    auto filter1 = IdentityFilter<double>();
    auto filter2 = filter1 * filter1 * filter1;
    while (true) {
        double value;
        std::cout << "input:";
        std::cin >> value;
        std::cout << "filtered: " << filter1.filtered_value(value) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "filtered: " << filter2.filtered_value(value) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The two values above should be always equal."
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to create child classes under `ISignalFilter` where they all only need to implement `filtered_value` and they should all work with the `*` operator automatically.

This code works, sort of. It compiles under `filter1 * filter1` and works, but as soon as I do `filter1 * filter1 * filter1`, I get a segfault.

Comment: I rather object to that this is “something similar to type classes”. The nearest C++ approximation to a type class should be a [concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)).

Comment: Haskell type classes are all about overloading, and have nothing to do with inheritance or subtyping or object-orientation. When you need to overload a bunch of related functions in Haskell, you create a type class. In C++ you just overload them. Concepts are something you can bolt onto overloading and they resemble proper type classes to a certain extent, but you can do everything without concepts, using just overloading.

Comment: It rather looks like you're implementing the Haskell *data type* `newtype SignalFilter a = SignalFilter (a -> a)` (and defining `SignalFilter f * SignalFilter g = SignalFilter (f . g)`), not anything related to a type class.

Comment: @HTNW Right, a C++-style class with a single method is isomorphic to a function. In C++ it can be replaced with an `std::function`, and in Haskell it's just a function.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you keep pointers to `ISignalFilter<F>` in `ProductFilter<T>`. But operations like `filter1 * filter1` return a temporary object, which gets destroyed at the end of the expression. And then your pointer becomes invalid.

Since you can't keep objects by value in this case, probably you need to use smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr<ISignalFilter<F>>`. Or, define a virtual copy function and keep copies in `ProductFilter<T>`, instead of pointers to possible invalid objects.

Comment: I don't understand yet why it compiles. I mean the temporary shouldnt bind to the non const reference. I must miss something ...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Just because something *compiles* does not guarantee it has *valid* behavior at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no of course not. I had spotted the issue, but now I am a little puzzled why its not an error at compile time already

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the temporary binds to the `this` argument, which is passed by pointer, no non-const reference. `filter1 * (filter1 * filter1)` would indeed be a compile-time error. (But you would still end up with the old runtime problem if it were taken as a const reference and a const pointer to that stored.)